# How to display a 2D array recordset from Access in Excel?

Tags: sql, excel, vba

How do I display the result of my SQL request?

In Access the SQL Query shows:
[image]

**My VBA code just displays the sectors name**. How can I display both Sector and Count result?

My VBA Code:

```vb
sQuery = "SELECT Sector, COUNT(*) FROM Test WHERE Search = 'FR' AND LaDate = #20/10/2021# GROUP BY Sector"
Set dbRecSet = New ADODB.Recordset
dbRecSet.Open Source:=sQuery, ActiveConnection:=dbConn

If (dbRecSet.RecordCount <> 0) Then
    Do While Not dbRecSet.EOF
        Debug.Print dbRecSet.Fields(0).Value
        dbRecSet.MoveNext
    Loop
End If
```

According to a comment I added

```
Debug.Print dbRecSet.Fields(1).Value
```

Does a way exist to display without a loop?

Comment: Does your current code work fine without error?

Comment: `Debug.Print dbRecSet.Fields(0).Value,dbRecSet.Fields(1).Value`

Comment: @Harun24HR  yes !

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Thank you, can I do it without loop like with `Debug.Print dbRecSet.GetRows` ?

Comment: GetRows returns an array, so you'll need to loop through that or paste it into a range, there is also GetString and CopyFromRecordset too.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Thank you so much its so clear now. Feel free to post your both comment as Answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to show field 1 also, like so:
`Debug.Print dbRecSet.Fields(0).Value,dbRecSet.Fields(1).Value`

There are also, `getrows`, `getstring` and `copyfromrecordset` available to you as well.  `GetRows` will return an Array, so will need looping or pasting to Excel and `getString` will return a String.  `CopyFromRecordset`, will paste the recordset contents to a range in Excel for you.